# How can I get the latest unity updates?

Tags: 11.04, unity

Well, I've tried using the PPA posted in [OMG UBUNTU!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-install-the-latest-unity-in-ubuntu-11-04/) . But nothing appears in the update manager.

So how do I get the updates without adding the ppa for `unity 3.8.16`?

Comment: I hate to ask, but did you follow something similar to the following: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:something/something sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install stuff_from_repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at the ppa - although the package is "natty" - its only available to oneiric... looks like the development team havent yet published it for natty.

Maybe an oversight or is it deliberate?

It could be that OMG Ubuntu jumped in too fast announcing this one when the devs havent actually got a natty repo ready.

I'm not going to test this myself, but if you definitely need this version then maybe edit your sources.list for the PPA and change the source distro from natty to oneiric.

Then hit that check button in update-manager one more time.

Confirm the unity version by running

```
unity --version
```

Looking at the comments on OMG! Ubuntu - there is a comment from Jorge Castro who said that 3.8.16 is going to be available in Natty Proposed either now or very soon.  Perhaps better to wait until there is an official Repository of the Natty Desktop PPA.

Comment: Shows up as 3.8.14 on my laptop.

Comment: It gives me `3.8.14` too.

Comment: @binarylife - as I said in my answer - omg! ubuntu doesnt always get these sort of things correct - have a look at the PPA on launchpad - there is only oneiric listed as the valid repos.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Ah yes, I didn't see this above at first sorry my bad. So there is no updates or it is too early to get these updates .

Comment: @binarylife - just looking at the comments on OMG! Ubuntu - there is a comment from Jorge Castro who said that 3.8.16 is going to be available in Natty Proposed either now or very soon.

Comment: I see. So it is a misunderstanding from the first !:D... well we should just wait then. Thx!

Comment: The stable update usually goes into the -proposed pocket, where it's tested for usually around a week before it goes into the update channel. So when you see something on the changes mailing list but you don't get it as a download it means it's still being tested.

Comment: I've added this question for how to turn on proposed updates: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-proposed-updates

Comment: @Jorge Castro: Well, I guess I should wait then. Since it is not in the proposed ppa also. But that OMG Ubuntu post was a bit misleading.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   gksu update-manager
```