# How do I add the "proposed" repository?

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to either test a fix that's been proposed or I want to volunteer to test stable release updates before they are pushed out to general users, how can I enable the "proposed" repository?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [wiki page on the -proposed repository](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed):

> To enable the proposed archive for Ubuntu 11.04 go to Applications→Ubuntu Software Center→Edit→Software Sources→Updates and ensure that natty-proposed is ticked.

[image]

[image]

Those directions map well to recent Ubuntu releases such as 10.10, 10.04, 9.10, etc.

---

Here are recent pictures from 12.04.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

## Using the Command Line

### Manual addition

With root permissions edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then look for the following line or add it yourself:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

(If you are not using precise, you can replace it with your current version)

Save your file. Then run `sudo apt-get update` and install the package you want to use `sudo apt-get install package/precise-proposed` or `sudo apt-get -t precise-proposed install package`.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed restricted main multiverse universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed-repositories.list"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [UBUNTU SOURCES.LIST AUTOMATIC GENERATOR](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/): includes all of the default repositories that are available through Ubuntu's own GUI, and you can also add other popular/useful PPAs like wine, virtualbox, tor, playdeb and getdeb, mozilla daily builds, medibuntu, etc...