# will using xubuntu decrease my power usage?

Tags: 11.04, power-management, xubuntu

I am battling with the absurd power usage of ubuntu 11.04. On windows 7 (which came preinstalled) I can get around 4:30 hours turning everything off (wifi, bluetooth, lowest brightness for screen) with same settings I get 2 hours with ubuntu. I was wondering if I install xubuntu will that help me reduce my power usage?

Comment: Partially, Xubuntu uses less resources than Ubuntu therefore it doesn't stress your computer as much, however they both come with kernel 2.6.38 which has a bug that increases the power usage.

Comment: I would use try lubuntu instead.. which should use much less resources than Xubuntu.

Comment: @Uri, does 2.6.39 have this bug? Thats the kernel I'm using.

Comment: Yes, they haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: Can you link to the bug report?

Comment: I'm not sure where is the bug report but here's an article commenting this.http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_kernel_regress2&num=1

Comment: And a proposed work around http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2638_aspm&num=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not on that scale.

To change your kernel to something that will increase your batter life, you need to use the kernel that is in the Proposed updates repository. For more on how to enable that, [look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository/49611#49611).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but almost definitely it wouldn't increase AC work hours by two times. Xubuntu has less tools and apps, and more optimized to be used in older, less powerful computers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is Ubuntu's fault. Battery life on a computer decreases over time. Ubuntu isn't going to steal two hours of battery life, I know this because I have a netbook which gets the same battery life as it did when it was running Windows XP. It is currently running Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think you understand, ubuntu is not able to manage the dual graphics cards on systems like mine. Thus it keeps the nVidia and on board intel graphics card all the time. Thus it is ubuntu's fault that I lose battery even if I am not using those cards. But to be fair it is the whole linux kernel's problem

Comment: Hmm...  Have you tried installing the nvidia drivers and looking at their configuration utilities?

Comment: That is the problem, nVidia does not give drivers for this tech (called nVidia optimus) otherwise it takes a day or two for new kernel update.

Comment: Try additional drivers utility. Are you using Linux 3?

Comment: I am using linux 3 and tried additional drivers.

Comment: Are there any hotkeys on your keyboard/bios settings to disable the secondary GPU?

Comment: No, that is the problem. It is supposed to be done automatically, that is what the nVidia optimus technology is for and that is what the drivers are supposed to do. But in typical nVidia manner they have not released the updated drivers for this.