# Bad ethernet connection in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: internet, connection, ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet slow on Ubuntu but not windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94770/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-but-not-windows)

I am using ubuntu 11.10 . If am connect to Internet by cable I have connection problems. Internet is always really slow and sometimes is unplugged. I tried it at my friends too and its slow too.

In windows i have no problem.

*Thank you for your help and sorry for my English*

Comment: Can you add some information about your hardware?.

Comment: RAM : 8 GiB, procesor : i7, 64 bit version Ubuntu 11.10, graphic card : amd 6770hd

Comment: Please provide the contents of `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: There is about 5.000 lines in syslog :-/

Comment: and almost on every line is : "Dec 20 15:39:18 ubuntu kernel: [14688.034056] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up"

Comment: Do you want upload whole syslog file ?

Comment: This is likely this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-backports-modules-3.0.0/+bug/839393). There is a fix in progress, please enable the proposed repository (http://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository) and update your machine.

Comment: Vote to close as it looks like a bug, not an answerable question.