# I'm not receiving Firefox updates, what is wrong?

Tags: firefox, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

Here:https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-stable
it is said:

> Aimed at Lucid and Maverick users who want to use a modern browser which starts faster
>     than you can brew your morning coffee

can you tell me which PPA should I use to have latest stable Firefox all the time?
Like for Chrome.

The other Questions are closed but they don't answer the question!

For example here: [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)

it's about versions prior to 11.04.

I have Oneiric and Firefox 9.0.1, but Firefox 10 was released couple of days ago.

May be I just need to wait?

Here is my sources.list (I have deleted ALL comments)

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Comment: The accepted answer in that question is for all versions of Ubuntu, you might want to check that your mirror is up to date.

Comment: how to check? I am running "apt-get update"

Comment: Please post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question.

Comment: @JorgeCastro done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the question you link to, the new version of Firefox will come to all supported releases. You don't have to add a PPA for that.

If you want to have it as quickly as possible, you could [enable the 'proposed' repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/49609/19679). But you should only do that if you want to help testing new packages (not just the Firefox one!) and are willing to submit bug reports.
.

Comment: alright, I just upgraded to Firefox 10.