# Can't install adobe-flash-properties-gtk

Tags: apt, flash, ppa

I am trying to see whether I can alter the settings of Flash to reduce the *huge* memory footprint—whether that succeeds is another issue—and came across advice regarding a settings tool that I am under the impression is in this package:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/adobe-flash-properties-gtk

To be clear, I am sure I am running precise. I suspect I am supposed to add a PPA here but I can't find the info on what its name is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is still in the Proposed repository. Meaning, that if you don't have the proposed repository activated you can not install these packages. To activate the proposed repository you can either use the GUI or the command line:

## Command Line

### Manual addition

With root permissions edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then look for the following line or add it yourself:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

(If you are not using precise, you can replace it with your current version)

Save your file. Then run `sudo apt-get update` and install the package you want to use `sudo apt-get install package/precise-proposed` or `sudo apt-get -t precise-proposed install package`.

### One liners

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed restricted main multiverse universe'" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t precise-proposed install adobe-flash-properties-gtk
```

Done.

## [Using the gui](https://askubuntu.com/a/49611/169736)

From the [wiki page on the -proposed repository](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed):

> To enable the proposed archive for Ubuntu 11.04 go to Applications→Ubuntu Software Center→Edit→Software Sources→Updates and ensure that natty-proposed is ticked.

[image]

[image]

Update your cache, and install the desired package.

Answer (score 1):

Select one of following package according to your architecture and ubuntu version:

12.04

64bit : http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0precise1_amd64.deb

32bit : http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0precise1_i386.deb

12.10

64bit : http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0quantal1_amd64.deb

32bit : http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0quantal1_i386.deb

13.04

64bit : http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0raring1_amd64.deb

32bit : http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0raring1_i386.deb

Download selected package using `wget`

Let's say your ubuntu version is 12.10 32bit.

```
wget http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0quantal1_i386.deb

dpkg -i adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.297-0quantal1_i386.deb
```

Comment: Sure but why can't I use the apt interface? That would make everything easier / more organized.

Comment: sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner" >> \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list'

Comment: Run that command to add repo if you are using Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring)