# How to install adobe-flash-properties-gtk on Saucy 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, flash, webcam

How can I install `adobe-flash-properties-gtk` on the new **Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy**? It was present since last version Raring 13.04. Is there another way to control the sites allowed to use the webcam?

The "partner" repository are enabled.

Cheers.

PS: instructions like this one "[Can't install adobe-flash-properties-gtk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342247/cant-install-adobe-flash-properties-gtk)" aren't written for Ubuntu later than Raring 13.04.

Comment: leonard, this issue should be resolved now, because the software was previously not in the repositories because it failed to build, feel free to try the instructions in the post you linked, and try again, and if it works, please mark my answer as "accepted" because it details why it was previously unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `adobe-flash-properties-gtk` previously was not available in Saucy.  It's source package, `adobe-flashplugin` was listed as in the partner repo's proposed section but was not yet actually in the repositories for the partner repo yet.   (see [this page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin) for the general information about the package.)

---

As of when I checked at 14:00 UTC-5 on November 14, 2013, the package has migrated from partner proposed to the actual partner repository and is now available.

It had previously been only in the partner proposed repository while it rebuilt with changes which repaired a "Failed to Build" issue.  It built correctly and apparently has migrated to the actual partner repository.

Comment: The package is now available in the actual partner repository!

Comment: @papukaija you're correct.  I made a note about that in an edit, and added a section that stated that it is now in the partner repos and why it wasn't in there previously.