# "Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 403 FORBIDDEN" error when trying to bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas

in the maas portal :ht   `tp://192.168.101.148/MAAS`,i can see 6 nodes,and the status are all:ready.

and my environments.yaml file is :

environments:

```
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: ht    tp://192.168.101.148:80/MAAS
    maas-oauth: "the key i get from the portal"
    admin-secret: super-secret-made-up-admin-key
    default-series: precise
```

and the error is below:

```
root@ubuntu:~# juju bootstrap
2013-09-11 15:55:31,557 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
2013-09-11 15:55:32,222 ERROR Failed to launch machine /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-e097fab8-1a11-11e3-a94b-0800270f346d/; attempting to release.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/launch.py", line 48, in start_machine
    instance_uri, cloud_init.render())
ProviderInteractionError: Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 403 FORBIDDEN
Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 403 FORBIDDEN
2013-09-11 15:55:32,404 ERROR Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, had better luck by using juju from the PPA instead of the default precise apt repository.

Install add-apt-repository tool:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Add Juju PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
```

Install Juju core:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju-core
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix in precise-proposed, enable this in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

- [How do I add the "proposed" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository)

And then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then restart MAAS with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/maas restart
```

this will solve your issue.

Comment: Could you provide references to this fix? Also, I know how to enable precise-proposed, but the asker may not. Could you be more verbose?