# gksudo nautilus error - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nautilus, 14.04, gksudo

I installed `gksudo` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when i run nautilus with gksudo

`gksudo nautilus` it asks for password, then gives error and then crashes

```
 (nautilus:19688): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkMessageDialog' to 'NautilusWindow'
 **
 ERROR:nautilus-window.c:2116:nautilus_window_get_slots: assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_WINDOW (window))
```

Though `sudo nautilus` seems to work fine

Thanks in Advance

---

Well, the problem has stopped occurring and `gksudo nautilus` works just fine. And I have absolutely no idea why this happened.

Any insight on  what my original problem was and how it got solved is highly appreciated.

Again thanks in advance.

Comment: try with sudo gksu nautilus /opt

Comment: I thought recent versions of Ubuntu use `pkexec` instead of gksu. You should not use `sudo nautilus` anyway

Comment: `pkexec nautlius` gives error `error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.`

`(nautilus:4939): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mentioned problem is now fixed in the same nautilus package version `1:3.10.1-0ubuntu8`. If you  still face this problem in Ubuntu 14.04 then update your nautilus package version from `1:3.10.1-0ubuntu8` to `1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9`.

`1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9` version of nautilus package is available at `trusty-proposed` repository. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/49611/202806) answer to enable trusty-prosed repository. After that update all the repositories by running `sudo apt-get update` command and install `nautilus 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9` package by running `sudo apt-get install nautilus` command on terminal.