# Can't get nautilus to go sudo with gksu

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, sudo, gksu

I was recently reading some linux articles and stumbled on a faster way to do sudo tasks the gui way by installing a package called **gksu-nautilus** which allows me perform tasks with root permissions without having to go through terminal.

I installed the package with synaptic and restarted nautilus with the command below:

```
nautilus -q
```

I then ran the lines `gksu nautilus` in terminal and got a prompt to enter my password, I entered it and immediately the errors below were displayed in terminal:

```
(nautilus:4062): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkMessageDialog' to 'NautilusWindow'
**
ERROR:nautilus-window.c:2116:nautilus_window_get_slots: assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_WINDOW (window))
```

I decided to try `sudo nautilus` , and got the same error. I'll really appreciate a solution to this problem.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/460497/299605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Nautilus is out of date. Go to https://askubuntu.com/a/460497/299605 for instructions on updating it.