# ceph version on ubuntu ports repository for armhf

Tags: arm, ceph, 16.04

I'm trying to install the lastest version of ceph on my armhf platform. I have already updated my installed release of ubuntu to the latest development of Xenial.

problem is, everytime i check, i find ceph version 0.94.5 (hammer) available for download. but when i check the actual repository at ports.ubuntu.com, i find version 9.2 (Infernalis) available. but the packages.[gz,bz2] file always lists version 0.94.5 instead.

what's the reason for this, and how can I fix this to install the latest available version ?

to explain that my questions is different from the proposed, i'm asking about the newest release which is *already* available in the repository.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a different issue, as the newer package versions mentioned are already available in the repository. just not updated in the packages file.

Comment: You'll find them in the `Packages` files for `xenial-proposed`, that's to say, they're in *testing* for an unreleased version of Ubuntu. As such, the question is the same. You're right about Ceph not supporting armhf by themselves, sorry about that.

Comment: you're right. last time i checked a couple of days ago they were still listed 0.94.5.

Comment: Enable `proposed` and you should be good to go, though: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository It can't be any more riskier than running 16.04 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

muru's point is right. It is now available in the Xenial proposed section. it wasnt like that a couple of days ago.