# How to reverse '-proposed' channel package upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, downgrade

I have an Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.18 64-bit VM, and in that VM I needed to test something in the `xenial-proposed` channel so I activated it in the `software-properties-gtk`, ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and installed all the upgrades from the `xenial-proposed` channel as I couldn't find a way to get it just to upgrade the package I needed.

Now however I wish to downgrade all the packaged upgraded to their `xenial-proposed` versions to their version in the stable/normal channels, but how can this be achieved? Can I use `ppa-purge` to do this? And if so, how?

If I just disable the `xenial-proposed` channel via the same means that I enabled it will the packaged installed and upgraded to their `xenial-proposed` versions start to receive updates again from the stable/normal channels once the version numbers there are higher than the installed or will I receive no updates at all then until I enable the `xenial-proposed` channel again?

Comment: Open your Software & Settings control panel and uncheck the -proposed repository. Random freezes may have many possible causes - better to troubleshoot than to guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adapting http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/how-to-downgrade-proposed-repository.html and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed, the packages installed from the `xenial-proposed` repository can be downgraded by doing the following (replace `xenial`with the codename of whichever release you are using):

1. Disable the `xenial-proposed` repository in `software-properties-gtk` as you have suggested.
2. In `/etc/apt/preferences.d`, create a file named `99-downgrade-proposed`.
3. Copy and paste the following lines into the file:

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=xenial
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=xenial-updates
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=xenial-security
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=xenial-backports
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=xenial-proposed
   Pin-Priority: -1
   ```
4. Run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`.
5. Delete the file by running `sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/99-downgrade-proposed`.

Answer (score 6):

1. Save a list of packages currently installed from the *proposed* suite:

   ```sh
   aptitude -F '%p' search "?narrow(?installed, ?archive($(lsb_release -sc)-proposed))" > /path/to/proposed-packages.txt
   ```

   *Attention:* Make sure that the resulting file size in bytes is well below 128 KiB or you’re likely going to run into issues in step 4.
2. Disable the *proposed* repository suite. If you don't know how, see [How do I add the "proposed" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49609/175814) and do the reverse.
3. Update the local package index:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Coerce all packages from the list from step 1 to the most recent known version for the current release:

   ```sh
   xargs -x -r -d '\n' -a /path/to/proposed-packages.txt -- sudo apt-get install -f -t "$(lsb_release -sc)" --
   ```

   After the removal of the repositories for the *proposed* suite and the package index update the most recent known package versions will be from *updates*, *security*, or the “bare” suite for your release depending on which other suite(s) you have enabled and what they contain.

P.S.: The above instructions are analogous to those of the removal of the *backports* suite and the down-grade of all its installed packages. Simply replace all instances of *proposed* with *backports*.