# 18.04 gnome desktop randomly freezes

Tags: drivers, gnome, freeze, amd-graphics

I have been using 18.04 for a few months and about every 2 days, there is random GUI freeze. It has happened during web browsing, coding and watching movies so I guess that it is not an application issue. It freezes completely including the cursor. I checked syslog and kernlog without any clues (last message is usually few mins before crash). Any recommendations to find out what's wrong? Atm I would appreciate any error message.

- GPU: AMD HD7970
- Driver: Mesa 18.0.5
- CPU: Ryzen 5

Thanks

Edit: running `apt-get update` and `upgrade` approx once per week.

Edit2: `apt list --installed | grep 'gnome\|extension\|shell'`

```
compiz-gnome/bionic,now 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/bionic,now 3.28.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0/bionic-proposed,now 3.28.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0/bionic,now 3.12.0-1build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-accessibility-themes/bionic,bionic,now 3.28-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
gnome-bluetooth/bionic,now 3.28.0-2 amd64 [installed]
gnome-calculator/bionic,now 1:3.28.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-calendar/bionic-proposed,now 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-control-center/bionic-updates,now 1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-control-center-data/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1.18.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-control-center-faces/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1.18.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-desktop3-data/bionic-proposed,bionic-proposed,now 3.28.2-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-disk-utility/bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-font-viewer/bionic,now 3.28.0-1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-getting-started-docs/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-initial-setup/bionic-proposed,now 3.28.0-2ubuntu6.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-keyring/bionic-updates,now 3.28.0.2-1ubuntu1.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-keyring-pkcs11/bionic-updates,now 3.28.0.2-1ubuntu1.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-mahjongg/bionic,now 1:3.22.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-menus/bionic,now 3.13.3-11ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-mines/bionic,now 1:3.28.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-online-accounts/bionic-proposed,now 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-orca/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.0-3ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-power-manager/bionic,now 3.26.0-1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-screensaver/bionic,now 3.6.1-8ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
gnome-screenshot/bionic,now 3.25.0-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
gnome-session-bin/bionic-updates,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-session-canberra/bionic,now 0.30-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-session-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-settings-daemon/bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-settings-daemon-schemas/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell/bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell-common/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/bionic,bionic,now 18.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/bionic,bionic,now 0.9.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-software/bionic-updates,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-software-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-software-plugin-snap/bionic-updates,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-startup-applications/bionic-updates,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-sudoku/bionic,now 1:3.28.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-system-log/bionic,now 3.9.90-5 amd64 [installed]
gnome-system-monitor/bionic-updates,now 3.28.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-terminal/bionic-proposed,now 3.28.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gnome-terminal-data/bionic-proposed,bionic-proposed,now 3.28.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-themes-extra/bionic,now 3.28-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-themes-extra-data/bionic,bionic,now 3.28-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-todo/bionic,now 3.28.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-todo-common/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-user-docs/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-user-guide/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
gnome-user-share/bionic,now 3.18.3-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-video-effects/bionic,bionic,now 0.4.3-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
language-pack-gnome-cs/bionic,bionic,now 1:18.04+20180423 all [installed]
language-pack-gnome-cs-base/bionic,bionic,now 1:18.04+20180423 all [installed,automatic]
language-pack-gnome-en/bionic,bionic,now 1:18.04+20180423 all [installed]
language-pack-gnome-en-base/bionic,bionic,now 1:18.04+20180423 all [installed]
language-selector-gnome/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 0.188.1 all [installed,automatic]
libgnome-autoar-0-0/bionic,now 0.2.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-bluetooth13/bionic,now 3.28.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-desktop-3-17/bionic-proposed,now 3.28.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-games-support-1-3/bionic,now 1.4.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-games-support-common/bionic,bionic,now 1.4.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
libgnome-keyring-common/bionic,bionic,now 3.12.0-1build1 all [installed,automatic]
libgnome-keyring0/bionic,now 3.12.0-1build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-menu-3-0/bionic,now 3.13.3-11ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-todo/bionic,now 3.28.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnomekbd-common/bionic,bionic,now 3.26.0-3 all [installed,automatic]
libgnomekbd8/bionic,now 3.26.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnautilus-extension1a/bionic,now 1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpam-gnome-keyring/bionic-updates,now 3.28.0.2-1ubuntu1.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libreoffice-gnome/bionic,now 1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libsoup-gnome2.4-1/bionic,now 2.62.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal/bionic-proposed,now 3.28.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
network-manager-gnome/bionic,now 1.8.10-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-pptp-gnome/bionic,now 1.2.6-1 amd64 [installed]
pinentry-gnome3/bionic,now 1.1.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
policykit-1-gnome/bionic,now 0.105-6ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
thunderbird-gnome-support/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:52.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Launch `software-properties-gtk`, open the `Additionnal Drivers` tab and see if some video driver can be found.

Comment: No additional drivers available. No proprietary drivers in use.

Comment: It's probably a bad GNOME extension. List which ones you have installed, and I'll take a look. Reply with @heynnema.

Comment: I did not install any extension as far as I know...

Comment: It looks like you've enabled **bionic-proposed**, and that may have installed software that's causing your problem. Disable **bionic-proposed** and downgrade that software to the standard 18.04.1 versions.

Comment: Ahh. It is possible! I wanted to help community with bug reporting, but it requires some log output. Just downgraded to main so I hope it fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Arghh..I have been too optimistic. As soon as I commented and closed tab, it happened again with one difference: working mouse cursor. :( @heynnema Any other idea?

Comment: When it freezes, hit ALT-F2, and when the GNOME entry box shows up, enter r to restart the GNOME shell. Let's see if that works.

Comment: @heynnema seems like restarting after downgrade fixed that. already 2 days without crash. Thanks!

Comment: Did you downgrade the packages from **bionic-proposed** or only remove the repository entry? What's the output of `apt-cache policy libgnome-desktop-3-17` now?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I disabled proposed and downgraded kernel version as heynnema adviced. Now I have newer revision than -24 without any issue. I think that both proposed+problematic kernel version caused that.. Installed version is: 3.28.2-0ubuntu1 (main)

Comment: Ok, but did you also downgrade other packages from *proposed* like `libgnome-desktop-3-17`? That’s what I tried to find out with the help of `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ah..yes, I think so. I used similar guide like https://askubuntu.com/questions/768849/how-to-reverse-proposed-channel-package-upgrade

Comment: Alright, that sounds good. Can you *confirm* that `libgnome-desktop-3-17` is downgraded from *proposed*. **What’s the output of `apt-cache policy libgnome-desktop-3-17`?**

Comment: I mentioned it in one of prev comments. Output is both 3.28.2-0ubuntu1 and main repos..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments...

- we downgraded from **bionic-proposed** to **main**
- we restarted the GNOME Shell with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>
- the computer should be rebooted at this time

So far the computer has been running fine!

Comment: Just happend again :( Now I can also say that alt+f2 does not work.

Comment: What kernel version are you running? Would it be 4.15.0-24-generic by chance? **uname -r** to find out. Any new GNOME extensions beside dock and appindicators?

Comment: Yep, 4.15.0-24-generic. I have not installed any new extensions. Nothing changed since I asked this question except `apt-get upgrade`. Syslog at given time: `Jul 11 18:05:22 xxx-desktop anacron[11926]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)`, empty line and then `Jul 11 18:20:44 xxx-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...`

Comment: Good guess, huh? -24 has some known problems. Try booting to a prior kernel, like -23, if you still have it installed, and run that way for a while and see if you continue to have problems. Report back. Does `dkms status` show anything?

Comment: Does anyone know how to downgrade from bionic-proposed to main? Many thanks!!!

Comment: @heynnema please add to this answer that kernel version was the root cause.. I'm facing kernel/gui freezes again on 20.04. It looks like hereditary disease..no recovery, no log..

Comment: @bigless Since using the "proposed" repo caused so much trouble, maybe not all of the software got reset when we disabled "proposed". Best to do a clean install of 20.04 or 20.10.

Comment: Argh..i'm trying to avoid that at all costs..so many settings..ssh keys, hosts, configs etc..I always forget something and it is gone..all that collateral damage with high probability that it doesn't help..you know that feeling for sure..

Comment: @bigless I know... but here you are... still having trouble... a year and a half later...