# 18.04.1 hangs and system freezes intermittently

Tags: 18.04, freeze

So my newly installed 18.04.1 system is freezing up intermittently. I tried looking at the kern.log and journalctl logs to find a pattern in the crash but I am unable to do so. Below I am attaching kern.log when the crash occured at 8.35. The log shows that the ath10k_pci firmware crashed. But I couldn't find these logs in previous crashes of the system.

```
Oct 15 08:32:36 scadza kernel: [   40.296008] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Oct 15 08:32:36 scadza kernel: [   40.296009] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Oct 15 08:32:36 scadza kernel: [   40.296011] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Oct 15 08:32:36 scadza kernel: [   40.296012] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Oct 15 08:32:36 scadza kernel: [   40.296013] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Oct 15 08:32:41 scadza kernel: [   44.844806] pci_raw_set_power_state: 28 callbacks suppressed
Oct 15 08:32:41 scadza kernel: [   44.844808] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Oct 15 08:32:41 scadza kernel: [   44.845120] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04] is released
Oct 15 08:32:41 scadza kernel: [   44.845174] pci_bus 0000:05: busn_res: [bus 05-39] is released
Oct 15 08:32:41 scadza kernel: [   44.845216] pci_bus 0000:3a: busn_res: [bus 3a] is released
Oct 15 08:32:41 scadza kernel: [   44.845256] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03-3a] is released
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.696342] wlp61s0: AP 28:3b:82:30:44:df changed bandwidth, new config is 2452 MHz, width 2 (2442/0 MHz)
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.746769] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid bb2e64fa-dc07-4bd5-88d6-d7ec03214f03)
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.746792] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1435
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.746798] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.747899] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.748723] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.748733] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750757] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: firmware register dump:
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750768] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [00]: 0x05030000 0x000015B3 0x0098747D 0x00955B31
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750774] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [04]: 0x0098747D 0x00060730 0x00000004 0x00000000
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750780] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [08]: 0x004089F0 0x00955A00 0x000A0B00 0x00400000
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750787] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750792] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x00910712 0x00000000 0x0091080D
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750798] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [20]: 0x4098747D 0x0040E7A8 0x00000000 0x0041EECC
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750804] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [24]: 0x809ABF81 0x0040E808 0x00000000 0xC098747D
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750811] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [28]: 0x809A65F4 0x0040E948 0x0041FED0 0x00434790
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750817] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [32]: 0x809A5D4B 0x0040E988 0x0040E9B0 0x0042D36C
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750822] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [36]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9A8 0x00000002 0x00000002
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750832] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [40]: 0x809FDBC5 0x0040EA58 0x0043D720 0x0042D718
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750838] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [44]: 0x809F8C46 0x0040EA78 0x0043D720 0x00000001
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750844] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [48]: 0x80911210 0x0040EAC8 0x00000010 0x004041D0
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750849] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [52]: 0x80911154 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00000000
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750855] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [56]: 0x8091122D 0x0040EB48 0x00000000 0x00400600
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750860] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750873] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400  14  14   3   3
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750886] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800  18  18  63  64
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750898] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  35  35  98  99
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750910] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000   7   7   8   7
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750922] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 2981 2981  20 212
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750934] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0  64   0
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750947] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  27  27  26  26
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.750959] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  193.850411] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  194.572193] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
Oct 15 08:35:10 scadza kernel: [  194.575225] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
Oct 15 08:35:11 scadza kernel: [  194.670431] ath10k_pci 0000:3d:00.0: device successfully recovered
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x8e, date = 2018-03-24
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-36-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-36.39-generic 4.15.18)
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic root=UUID=7ce775dd-624e-4e92-b6ad-668031f4f57c ro
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Oct 15 08:37:05 scadza kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
```

hwinfo of the wifi card :

```
PCI 3d00.0: 0282 WLAN controller
[Created at pci.378]
Unique ID: hVJg.Jw5XE2Z_aN5
Parent ID: HnsE.ksuLhcM8PM3
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:3d:00.0
SysFS BusID: 0000:3d:00.0
Hardware Class: network
Model: "Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter"
Vendor: pci 0x168c "Qualcomm Atheros"
Device: pci 0x003e "QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter"
SubVendor: pci 0x1a56 "Bigfoot Networks, Inc."
SubDevice: pci 0x1435 
Revision: 0x32
Driver: "ath10k_pci"
Driver Modules: "ath10k_pci"
```

If you need other logs, please let me know. Or you could tell me the steps to collect all the relevant logs when system freezes again.

I think I have the same problem as mentioned in this question : [Ath10k and QCA6174 causing PCIe errors, firmware crashes, and connection drops?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063679/ath10k-and-qca6174-causing-pcie-errors-firmware-crashes-and-connection-drops)

But the solution provided there can't be applied to my system. As the [atheros github repository](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1) doesn't have the latest version for my firmware version `WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1` . (Notice the Z at the end)

As requested, output of the `sudo lshw -c memory`

```
*-firmware                
     description: BIOS
     vendor: Alienware
     physical id: 0
     version: 1.2.4
     date: 01/25/2018
     size: 64KiB
     capacity: 15MiB
     capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
*-memory
     description: System Memory
     physical id: 2c
     slot: System board or motherboard
     size: 32GiB
   *-bank:0
        description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
        product: 16ATF2G64HZ-2G3H1
        vendor: 009C0B160000
        physical id: 0
        serial: 18C7AEFA
        slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        size: 16GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
   *-bank:1
        description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
        product: 16ATF2G64HZ-2G3H1
        vendor: 009C0B160000
        physical id: 1
        serial: 18C7AEF4
        slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
        size: 16GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
*-cache:0
     description: L1 cache
     physical id: 30
     slot: L1 Cache
     size: 256KiB
     capacity: 256KiB
     capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
     description: L2 cache
     physical id: 31
     slot: L2 Cache
     size: 1MiB
     capacity: 1MiB
     capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
     description: L3 cache
     physical id: 32
     slot: L3 Cache
     size: 8MiB
     capacity: 8MiB
     capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     configuration: level=3
*-memory UNCLAIMED
     description: Memory controller
     product: Sunrise Point-H PMC
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
     version: 31
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:dd12c000-dd12ffff
```

My bionic-proposed repository is disabled.ie. I am not using any proposed packages.

I ran [Memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm#linux) for two complete passes. It took 3 hours to complete in total and there were no errors.

Comment: @heynnema : Could you take a look at this question? The crash occured once more this morning.

Comment: At this moment, I believe all  802.11ac wlan drivers are very buggy and highly unreliable...

Comment: Edit your question with `sudo lshw -c memory`, and then boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run `memtest` for at least one complete pass. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: ps: if you're running with "proposed", see https://askubuntu.com/questions/768849/how-to-reverse-proposed-channel-package-upgrade

Comment: @heynnema : I added the required info in the question. Also I ran memtest for 2 complete passes and there were no errors.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 18.10 and see if the problem is still there. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema : Could you tell me what are you suspecting the problem to be? Wouldn't the problem be the same if I am booting from usb as the firmwares would still be same? Also the problem occurs randomly so I might have to use the usb for longer time to notice it. Aren't the logs enough to pinpoint the errors?

Comment: The problem is probably with the QCA6174 and the firmware, but booting to a Live DVD/USB **can** eliminate other software problems quickly. Are you running wireless mostly, or can you connect via a wired connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I resolved my issues with Ubuntu 18.04 freezing and hanging. It was happening after 5-10 minutes of me logging in recently.

One aspect that led me to the resolution was the fact that sometimes during boot, my Alienware 15R3 would complain that it cannot find the Media i.e. boot drive. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 in dual boot on my 1TB ssd drive. So during boot, I used to get messages like "Checking Media Presence..." two times and then it would go into Dell SupportAssist mode. I used to restart the machine and then it would detect the ssd again. This triggered an idea in my brain that may be my SSD drive is loose and hence bios can't detect the drive.

I opened up my laptop after following the youtube turotials. Removed the SSD drive and cleaned that area and reinserted it back again. After doing that, I haven't had a single issue of the Ubuntu hanging up on me.

So if you are facing a hanging/freezing issue with a laptop and you are sometimes getting messages like "Checking Media presence.." during boot, may be your SSD drive is loose and you need to put it back in place properly and make sure it is firmly held. Hopefully, this will help someone out there.