# Unable to find packagename 'xenial-proposed'

Tags: 16.04, openstack

1. setup: Ubuntu 16.04lts on vmware exsi vm as guest os.
2. procedure: installing openstack following url http://conjure-up.io/
3. installation issue: unbound local error; following instructions at
   Testing/EnableProposed (ubuntu wiki).
4. using the following command to upgrade xenial-proposed as item 3: 
   sudo apt-get install packagename/xenial-proposed
5. getting error as shown in screen shot attached:

[image]

Please help suggest.

Comment: There is no package with the name `packagename/xenial-proposed` . The error is valid.

Comment: Hi,
Would you please suggest how to follow instructions under selective upgrade at this url: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

Comment: Well you're supposed to replace "packagename" with the name of the package you want..

Comment: Why do you even want to enable the proposed repository? It is not something one should generally be doing.

Comment: @dobey I will add this note into my answer.

Comment: Dobey,
 conjure-up at http://conjure-up.io/ process helps loading openstack on ubuntu16.04lts but it fails with an error I mentioned in my earlier post. This particular error can be fixed following through this url: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed 
Xenial-proposed package is mentioned in this url as a fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add the "proposed" repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository)

Answer (score 2):

There is no package named 'xenial/proposed', however there is a repository called that name.

**Note: enabling the repository `xenial/proposed` is not really encuraged because it contains bleeding edge developtment packages which may even be able to break your setup**

To easily enable all the repositories you can change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And the following section is a compressed enable all repositories `sources.list` you can copy&paste or change your `sources.list` to look alike:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

After done this edit, simply do an `sudo apt-get update` to cache the new enabled repositories, from there you can install whatever you need.

Comment: Nice work :) I guess the OP is trying to add that repository.  `Xenial-proposed`

Comment: Hi Serverus,
Any suggestion on how to retrieve this specific package xenial-proposed.

Comment: @Dhiman I'm sorry i missed the essential line in my `sources.list` example which is `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse`, I have corrected my answer right now.

Comment: Serverus, Videonauth & Dobey,
I am still getting the same error for which I followed instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed and those you have suggested herein.
I get this error while doing: conjure-up openstack

Comment: missed the error, here it is:
UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'creds' referenced before assignment.