# Ubuntu apt zsys error

Tags: apt, 20.04

So I keep getting this error when doing an upgrade, but I cant find a solution on how to resolve it.  Im on Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information...
Done Calculating upgrade... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
Setting up zsys (0.4.6) ... dpkg: error processing package zsys (--configure):  installed zsys package 
post-installation script subprocess returned error exit  status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:  zsys ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to solve the error?

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in `zsys` here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsys/+bug/1886214.

One solution is to do this:

1. [Enable `proposed` branch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository) in your repository and update.

```
$ echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed-repositories.list
$ sudo apt update
```

2. Install `zsys` `v0.4.7` (as of today, 10 Aug 2020) by:

```
$ sudo apt -t $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed install zsys
```

3. Remove the proposed branch if you don't want it to stay:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/proposed-repositories.list
$ sudo apt update
```

Comment: I've been waiting months for this answer, thanks heaps.

Comment: I needed to upgrade `sudo apt upgrade zsys` to make this work