# screencast not working ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, screenshot, desktop-recording

taking a screenshot or partial screenshot works fine, but when i try to record and click on the record button, it prompts the timer on the top bar and instantly disappears and, eventually, recording doesn't happen. And this is happening in just a second. Why am I encountering this problem? i had Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I upgraded to 21.10 and then to 22.04 LTS. Please help me.

Comment: works fine for me on new vanilla install 22.04 LTS

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I was excited to use this new feature, but was disappointed when I discovered it wasnt working

Comment: Similar issue has been resolved by reinstalling gstreamer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410205/screen-recorder-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Given the suggested solution, maybe this is more common on upgraded systems rather than on freshly installed 22.04.

Answer (score 10):

Delete the cached gstreamer directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: In case `rm -rf ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0` does not work, just run it with administrator/root privileges.
`sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0` Thanks @Janghou.

Comment: Now, records for 0.5s and doesn't save anything

Answer (score 1):

**First solution**

Enables the proposed archive: [How do I add the "proposed" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49609)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipewire
```

This will update your pipewire version to the proposed version (updated to: 10/11/2022):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipewire/0.3.48-1ubuntu3

Disables the proposed archive.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Second solution**

Demote the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-pipewire=0.3.48-1ubuntu1 pipewire=0.3.48-1ubuntu1 libpipewire-0.3-0=0.3.48-1ubuntu1 libspa-0.2-modules=0.3.48-1ubuntu1 libpipewire-0.3-modules=0.3.48-1ubuntu1 pipewire-bin=0.3.48-1ubuntu1
```

With both solutions unfortunately the mouse pointer is not captured in any case.