# Screen recorder not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I just upgraded from 20.04 to **22.04** on a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ITL05. I wanted to use the new screen recorder, so I pressed PrtSc, which brought up the normal options. The screenshot function seems to be working fine, but **when I choose to record, the symbol at the top of the screen pops up for a split second, then vanishes and nothing happens**. Any ideas about how to fix this??

Comment: In my case it wasn't working because I had removed "Videos" from ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs and /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults .

Comment: I'm just going to install 20.04 again and use it. As I'm a newbie at this and can't do anything without my Simple screen recorder. It's my business and wish I had know ahead of time this would make it quit working. And no other one will launch either.

Comment: @WilliamHensley If you desperately need a screen recorder, I would highly recommend using OBS Studio. If not then simply open a terminal and enter the command `sudo apt reinstall gstreamer1.0-pipewire`. The screen recorder in 22.04 is greatly improved over the 20.04 version.

Comment: In my case installing `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` helped ([source](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/please-help-me-with-obs.156406/))

Comment: @christian_js you mean the Ubuntu's default screen recorder? That one doesn't record sound.

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė I'm aware of that, but regardless, it wasn't working.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have a few ideas. I used htop to view my running processes to figure out a little about the Screencast program.
Mine is here "usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Screencast"
You can run the program and then check a few on your log files and look at the activity.

```
cd /var/log
```

The -f option for tails lets you watch whats happening. Or just use *tail -n 20 syslog* and look at the last 20 lines in the log file.

other ideas...Using different file manager? limited user account? Screencast folder missing? not a Gnome desktop or installed different one?

```
tail -f syslog
```

And see if you find anything interesting. Also check auth.log, kern.log, Xorg.1.log, ....

Mine created a folder in */home/userMe/Videos/Screencasts* and all my Screencast show up there in WebM format.

Let us know what you figure out

**Update:** Known issue for upgrades:

Seems that gstreamer-1.0 isn't upgrading correctly and the fix:

```
cd ~/.cache
rm -rf gstreamer-1.0
```

or that might work

```
sudo apt reinstall gstreamer1.0-pipewire
```

Comment: i too have the same issue & found below in syslog - Any comments? 
`pc dbus-daemon[6329]: [session uid=1000 pid=6329] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.Screencast' requested by ':1.38' (uid=1000 pid=6494 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
pc dbus-daemon[6329]: [session uid=1000 pid=6329] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.Screencast'
JS LOG: Failed to create pipeline: Gst.ParseError: no element "pipewiresrc"
pc gnome-shell[6494]: Error starting screencast
pc gnome-shell[6494]: D-Bus client with active sessions vanished`

Comment: Thanks Czar, it seems like **gstreamer** was the issue. I reinstalled it and the Screencast program works fine now.

Comment: The removal command worked for me, thanks :)

Comment: deleting cached dir fixed it!

Comment: wfm. Here's the relevant Ubuntu bug report for anyone who wants to dive deeper: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1963264

Comment: Ubuntu's default Screencast works well, unfortunatelly it doesn't record sound. I need to record my voice over the screen.

Comment: I really don't know how much time did it take to try to find a solution for this problem! Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 11):

As @Janghou [specified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410205/screen-recorder-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04#comment2453775_1410249), just removing the cache directory solved it:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to run `peek -b ffmpeg`