# Screen recorder now only records 1-2s of motion, rest is static, in Ubuntu 22.04.1LTS

Tags: gnome, 22.04, video, wayland

The built-in screen recorder used to be solid! But at some point over the last few months it's become really unreliable; I don't know what changed.

I'm on Wayland, which is singularly responsible for most of my Ubuntu woes, but it did previously work. Which was amazing because pretty much every other screenshot/screencapture app has given up on wayland.

Two things seem to be noticably weird:

1. no errors; video is recorded and saved apparently fine, yet when I play one back motion only shows for the first second or so, after that it's just a static image for the duration of the recording.
2. Gnome's built in video viewer plays it like this - with the video all squashed over to the left. VLC and MPV show it properly.
   [image: screenshot]

Note: I have tried all the solutions from [Screen recorder not working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410205/screen-recorder-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04) which is also reporting problems with this part of ubuntu 22.04, though the symptoms are different. Specifically I have tried: `sudo apt reinstall gstreamer1.0-pipewire` `rm ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0`  xdg-desktop-portal-gnome is already installed. `grep -i screencast /var/log/syslog` returns only pairs of lines like "Activating..." and "Successfully activated".

EDIT: I have tried 22.10, and it appears it works on that, but I'd rather stay on LTS if possible.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I seem to have the same problem.

Comment: @Kris Nope. It's quite annoying!