# How to upgrade to the latest Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity

I am using the 4.24.0 version of Unity and I would like to upgrade to the LATEST version.

Is it possible to upgrade to it without having to download and compile (as per [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)) and IF yes, how? (And what problems might occur if any)

NOTE - I already looked into this question: [How can I get the latest unity updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49577/how-can-i-get-the-latest-unity-updates) but it does not answer the question nor does it have any information about the latest.

UPDATE - There is NO 5.x released yet.

Comment: Where? V5 hasn't been uploaded anywhere...or  finished for that matter.

Comment: Oh how nice. I asked where did they see this and guess what. Yeah, it was the launchpad for unity here: https://launchpad.net/unity/5.0 Am guessing confused between a milestone and something not yet released. Sorry for the trouble. I will anyway change the question for the latest version (4.26 right now)

Comment: Actually am trying to avoid downloading tar and compiling. Let me add that to it.

Comment: Looks as if you are out of luck as the LP page states it is not yet packaged. The INSTALL has specific advice, but it looks as if it will take a moderate amount of effort http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/INSTALL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG!Ubuntu! recently published an article which contained information about [installing Unity v5.0 in 11.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-install-unity-5-0-in-ubuntu-11-10/).

In order to upgrade to Unity v5.0, you need to add the Unity team's PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/staging
```

*Note that this is a testing PPA and consider yourself sufficiently warned against doing this.*

And then, do an update and upgrade and your Unity version will be bumped up to version 5.0.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

If you need help downgrading from Unity 5.0, take a look at the following questions:

- [Error while purging  PPA from Unity 5.0 testing repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96433/error-while-purging-ppa-from-unity-5-0-testing-repository)
- [How do I reinstall Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity)

---

If you are wanting to try out Unity versions that are not held in a PPA, you can only do it by compiling from the source.

- [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)