# How do I reinstall Unity?

Tags: unity

I tested out Unity 5, and of course, it broke things, so I tried downgrading by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
```

It removed Unity completely.

```
apt-get install unity
```

seemed to work, but the login screen now offers only Gnome.

How do I get back to Unity 4?

Answer (score 27):

plus one for me. But with this, I got it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Seems to wired, and I think it was more luck than brain, but it worked for me.

Comment: Was having a problem recently with unity lagging like crazy when alt tabbing, tried a few things tweaking in the ccsm gui but was only able to get things half better, reinstalled unity as described here rebooted and I'm in good shape, thx.

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate. Tell us why you choose to use the particular commands you have mentioned.

Comment: @Venki it just refreshes the repository, and reinstall ubuntu-desktop and unity. Not sure what else needs to be explained

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It looks like you were still running 5.0 and then you just purged it and reinstalled it.

Either way, it did work for me. You might need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> at the login screen and try it through tty1.

Comment: mmmm-nope, it doesn`t change a thing.