# launcher, top panel disappeared and global menu & hud disabled

Tags: unity, compiz, lightdm

This morning, I removed all the unity-webapps-something and didn't pay attention that removing unity-webapps-service or unity-webappas-common required to remove other key packages:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bamfdaemon hud indicator-appmenu indicator-sound libbamf3-1 libunity-webapps0 lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure unity unity-tweak-tool unity-webapps-common
  unity-webapps-service xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 13 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 10.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 458920 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing unity-tweak-tool ...
Removing lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure ...
Removing unity ...
Removing indicator-sound ...
Removing indicator-appmenu ...
Removing hud ...
Removing libbamf3-1:amd64 ...
Removing bamfdaemon ...
Removing xul-ext-unity ...
Removing xul-ext-websites-integration ...
Removing unity-webapps-common ...
Removing libunity-webapps0 ...
Removing unity-webapps-service ...
```

Now, that I login to my unity session, I have no launcher, no top panel, global menu integration and hud are disabled.

- I reinstalled all the packages removed above and restarted the computer but in vain.
- I reconfigured these packages but in vain (sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity)
- I issued:  unity --replace and compiz --replace  but in vain.

Any Ideas please. this is kind of frustrating.

PS: At the greeter stage, everything is fine. It's only when I log in. 
I can also login to my gnome Fall back session without problems.

Comment: Did you re-install unity?  Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity).

Comment: Thanks, it was a matter of re-enabling the unity plugin.

Answer (score 0):

SOrry! Just got the answer here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Since Unity package was removed, the unity plugin in Compiz manager got disabled. So opening compiz manager and re-enabling the plugin did the trick.