# Unity sidebar and window frames disappear when I click on an icon with 2 or more dots (multiple windows)

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, launcher, icons

How can I restore Unity to it's original installation settings?

**Background**

In normal operation, Unity shows up to three dots next to an icon on the left sidebar when the application has 2 more more windows open. E.g. multiple file manager windows or chrome etc.

**The problem**

Usually, when I click on such icons with the dots, I am expecting the display to 'scale'/zoom-out to show the windows (expose on the Mac is similar). This used to happen but today what happens is that when I click on the icon, the Ubuntu side-bar disappears and the frames around all the currently displayed windows disappear such that I can no longer move them.

**Working toward a solution...**

I know that this worked fine after installation, and for quite a while after that, several months in fact.

What I'm looking for is a sequence of commands that return the Unity window system back to that state where it worked.

A temporary work-around that I know of is `setsid unity` which I can issue in a terminal window (if one happens to be open at the time the unity side bar and window frames disappear). What `setsid unity` does is restore the unity sidebar and side frames - but not permanently - in this case - because clicking on an icon with dots by it still causes unity to disappear. So in this case, `setsid unity` does not deal with the root cause.

So, I'm looking for something to permanently return the state of the unity window manager, so that this problem does not matter.

**Note:** 
I have not tinkered with my setup in this regard what-so-ever. The problem just seemed to happening. I can only guess that closing the lid of my laptop put it into standby which caused some kind of upset (usually it's fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A performed a standard update may fix the issue and then a re-install of unity:

[How do I reinstall Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity)

At least one of these 2 steps fixed the issue for me - by that I mean the update may be enough.