# ERROR Code: Unity on 14.04 would not load

Tags: 14.04, crash, unity-greeter

Unity 14.04 is failing to load after an upgrade from 12.04. I think it is because it was an incomplete upgrade and there was some errors. I finally got it to recognize me and let me login into Unity with my user name and password but then it crashes. When I went into the terminal I searched for errors but have no clue what the below code describes:

```
X Error of failed request: Bad Request (invalid request code or no such operation)
major opcode of failed request: 155 (glx)
minor opcode of failed request: 19 (X_GLXqueryserverstring)
serial number of failed request: 22
Current serial number in output stream: 22
openConnection: connect: no such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at: 0
script for ibus started at run_im.
script for auto started at run_im.
script for default started at run_im.
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_i386-linux-gnu_libgtk-3-0_gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0.0.crash) main process (2007) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_sbin_unity-greety.114.crash) main process (2008) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: "did ~/.xsession-errors a second time" in what context? what is your actual question?

Comment: Unity wasn't Loading after an upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. I finally got it to login, but it now crashes and says system error, report problem? When I go into the terminal and type xsession-errors I was given the above results

Answer (score 0):

As you have a serious problem, and you're a new user and you're probably panicking right now, I'm cutting you some slack to tell you to:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Log in on the console (the big black screen you just arrived to)
3. Point you to: [How to reinstall Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity)

Comment: Thank you Fabby, I will try this. I'm definitely not panicking, just don't know where to go. Thanks! sorry I can't upvote you! when I can I'll be sure to pass it on!

Comment: No need to thank me.  On this site, upvoting an answer (clicking on the grey up-arrow above the "0" of my answer is considered a *big* thank you!

Comment: I require 15 reputation points... and Just so you know, it didn't work, still won't let me login, followed the directions from the page. I think it's time to uninstall, reinstall

Comment: Once you've *got the 15 reputation*, come back and upvote!  ;)

Comment: I do not think he'll come back again. Perhaps he now uses Windows