# Undo apt-get command that removed a large number of packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, 64-bit, system

I installed `libatk 1.0.-0:i386` on my 64-bit system by mistake. It removed almost all from my system starting with indicators ending with Eclipse and other programs. So then I removed `libatk` and called `apt-get autoremove`. Now I have a black screen instead of GUI and it's only possible to work from terminal. In apt log there are a huge number of packages, very huge. I even couldn't read them all. Is there any way to automatically install them?

Comment: I would start with a re-install of the desktop. See http://askubuntu.com/a/95878/15811

Comment: And then, in a text editor, prepare a command like "`sudo apt-get install <huge list of packets>`" until you have something that looks OK. Then, execute that command in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Юрий, [re-installing your desktop](https://askubuntu.com/a/95878/15811) seems indeed the prudent way to go, but *before you do* re-install, I would also read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).

You're *definitely* user type 4!