# Panel is missing in Ubuntu 14.04 with Pantheon

Tags: 14.04, panel, elementary, pantheon

I installed Pantheon desktop in my Ubuntu 14.04, as described in [this guide](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/08/install-elementary-os-pantheon-desktop-environment-ubuntu-14-04/), but when I log in with Pantheon the Panel doesn't appear:

[image: desktop with no top panel]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you no longer have the Ubuntu UI (called Unity), but the Pantheon UI.  And the Pantheon UI has no Unity-panel.  So what you see now is absolutely normal.

To revert back follow the steps in [the link you used to install Pantheon](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/08/install-elementary-os-pantheon-desktop-environment-ubuntu-14-04/) in reverse order, then go here: [How do I reinstall Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity) and your Unity-panel will re-appear!