# Pantheon Desktop Environment not installed correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments, elementary

So I recently installed *Pantheon* and now its causing me problems.

First of all I installed it but it isn't present at the login screen also and I can't seem to uninstall it via *ppa purge* or *synaptic package manager*, <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcut has stopped working , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> isn't working and my multi-touch has been inverted and some more problems.

I would really have my settings back to the ones before I installed *Pantheon*.

P.S This is obviously an Ubuntu question as this is just a DE, not Elementary OS! **;-)**

Comment: what pc you have?

Comment: I have a dell inspiron 15r N5110 model.

Comment: Voted to Re-open as well.  Edited to make question clearer.  @personinsack: Our apologies, we get so many questions for support for ElementaryOS that if we see "Elementary" our brain shuts down and we close!  **;-)**  Additionally, did you [re-install unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity) yet?
Could you also [edit] your question and add how you installed it exactly?  That'll help us to help you to get rid of it...  >:)

Comment: @Fabby thanks for reopening the question but since I thought I wouldn't be getting any help regarding this question, I reinstalled ubuntu. so pretty much my problem is solved.

Comment: Closing process "problem went away all by its own" started...  For the future: "On hold" doesn't mean "closed"...  You can still edit your question and revamp it so it's acceptable to the community. (or point out that it was acceptable all along!)  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for the advice. I am new on this community so I pretty much don't know how most of the stuff works here, anyway i will keep in mind  about the hold thing.