# How to I restore ubuntu-desktop / unity / gnome back to it's original state

Tags: unity, 14.10

I tried to install KDE on ubuntu, which involved me doing an `sudo apt remove --purge *unity`, a full install of kde and other involved packages. The problem is that somewhere in between I really screwed up and it didn't work, so I gave up and tried going back to unity, but now after getting rid of KDE and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and unity it does not look at all like it was before, windows don't have the exit/minimize/maximize buttons, there is no dash, CTRL+SHIFT+T doesn't work, the top bar is missing all of the system control buttons (shutdown, settings, etc). I do not know how to fix this and I've tried everything, how can I completely reset ubuntu-desktop and unity?

The top bar that is always visible:
[image]

Window control bar in nautilus (and every other window):
[image]

Comment: Try running `apt-get install unity*`. It should reinstall everything that was purged.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this method of reinstalling unity:

[How do I reinstall Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity)

I've had similar issues in the past when exploring additional desktop environments and this is the procedure I used to get Unity back up and running.

Comment: That was one of the original pages I used as reference to fix my problem but no luck, I've updated the post with pictures so you have a better visual idea of what is going on.