# Panel Icons Missing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, panel

I am a new Ubuntu user having a problem with my Ubuntu 14.04 panel icons [not properly displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OOeX.jpg). Before this happened I had a problem to boot a system - it took years to display anything after the login screen. The missing icons are for the network, locale, Thunderbird, power, sound, and system.

PS

If this is a duplicate of another question then sorry I couldn't find the  right link, hope you to share a link.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 14.04 you downloaded directly from ubuntu.com? Or are you using a derivative like Ubuntu MATE?

Comment: I downloaded system installator from ubuntu.com.  _BTW thanks for question edit :)_

Comment: Have you recently removed any software? And it was no problem.

Comment: A week or earlier I might have reinstalled something. The problem  appeared last night.

Comment: I would say try updating the system via the command line with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and see if it gives you any errors.

Comment: Except for my usual Steam vs Wine collision all the system is OK and up to date.

Comment: `unity --reset-icons` displayed icons in the login screen but it happened only there. And I have to reorder panel icons now ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Hold **Alt** while right-mouse clicking on the panel.
2. select **Add to Panel**
3. Add indicator Applet Complete
4. Finish

Answer (score -1):

It is possible something happened to damage or remove the icons that Unity is trying to reload. So you may want to try reinstalling the Ubuntu desktop environment as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

This may be slightly overkill for just some missing icons but it may fix your problem.

Comment: I found some easy way to deal with it temporarily. Changed icons with Unity Tweak Tool. It seems that I have problem with Ubuntu-mono-light icons only. How do I reinstall them?

Comment: reinstalling meta package won't pull any other packages