# Unity Missing/Broken?

Tags: unity

I changed some settings in Unity and then I ran the `Setsid unity` command and now every time I try and boot up Ubuntu I can login just fine but the desktop is completely empty besides my background picture. I'm not sure how to fix it as I can't open the terminal or anything. Please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sphiinx, welcome to ask.ubuntu. have you tried to re-install unity? http://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity

Comment: How would I do that when I can't access the terminal?

Comment: press Ctrl + Alt + F2 - and you will get be able to log into the terminal.

Comment: How did you "change the settings on your unity"? in compiz?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> - and you will get be able to log into the terminal. Once you are logged in, reinstall unity by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Once that is done, restart your machine. If that doesn't solve your problem then:

If you have Compiz, you might also need to reset all changes made by Compiz:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

If you have Unity tweak tool, you might also need to do reset it:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

If that also fails, then maybe deleting the settings files:

```
rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1
```

Lastly, you could try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: I did all that and I still can't seem to fix it. Also I don't have the folder /org/compiz. Sometimes when I login all the stuff on the screen flashes like the folders and such.

Answer (score 0):

- Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or right click on desktop, select Open Terminal)
- On terminal run: `unity --reset`