# Cannot reinstall unity on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit) on Virtualbox

Tags: gui

I have set up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit) on Virtualbox (on Windows 8.1) for many days but this morning, while I was using Ubuntu, the computer became very slow and lag, the memory came up to 90% so I quickly shutdown the machine. After that, I started it again but there was an error.

I cannot login to that machine anymore. I can assure that this is not Virtualbox's errors because I can still login into another tty by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1 => F6</kbd>. But when I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, it just appeared a dark screen, so I think that is GUI error. I have typed this command: `

```
sudo apt-get reinstall unity-desktop
```

but it said:

```
Invalid operation reinstall
```

Does anyone know this error, please help me, thanks a lot.

Below is some images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the error message that you saw?

Comment: @heynnema As mentioned above, it just appeared "Invalid operation reinstall" when I typed `sudo apt-get reinstall unity-desktop` and entered.
I will add some images on the topic.

Comment: The command should be `--reinstall` not `reinstall`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reinstall Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity)

Comment: @Egrimo Oops ! This error has happened again. But this time, I don't know what is the reason like before (the reason is shutdown incorrectly). And I have tried these commands but they didn't matter:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
`sudo apt-get install unity`
Please help me, thanks a lot. Notice that I can't set up Ubuntu again because there're a lot of important data on it !!

Comment: @MinhAndrew Can you login and desktop doesn't seen or you're in login-loop ?

Comment: @Egrimo No, it's not a login-loop error. Because I turned off the password-asking when start so it isn't ask me. It just appears Ubuntu start screen and then is a black screen.And i think desktop doesn't seen.

Comment: @MinhAndrew After seeing black screen can you reach Terminal ? If you do, you can try this command(maybe unity isnt enabled by default) `sudo apt-get install compizconfig--settings-manager && ccsm` This will open a GUI app namely "Compiz Config Settings" There, you can find Unity plug-in and enable it.

Comment: @Egrimo Yes, I can use the terminal in tty mode. I have tried your recommended commands but it seems they didn't work, that GUI app didn't appear on the screen. There're just a few warnings, and the last warning is: `CurrentScreenNum = gtk.gdk.display_get_default().get_default_screen().get_number()` and `AttributeError: 'NonType' object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'`. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @Egrimo Oops ! I can't believe that this time, when I turned the computer on, it appeared the screen normally, no dark screen !!! Can anyone tell me what the hell is going on? I can login to Ubuntu normally, all softwares, apps and data is safe, nothing is lost, unlike before !!!

Comment: Notice that before, I have sometimes pressed Fn + F1 to change the resolution, is it a reason ?

Comment: @MinhAndrew It's probably the reason that you rebooted the OS and fixed before but needed to reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```