# Error while purging  PPA from Unity 5.0 testing repository

Tags: 11.10, unity, ppa, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reinstall Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity)

I installed Unity 5.0 to test it but I am having many problems with it, for example, the lenses don't work. But when I tried to downgrade, it didn't work.

I tried: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging`

And I got the following warning:

> PPA to be removed: unity-team staging Warning:  Could not find package
>   list for PPA: unity-team staging

I used the article [how to install Unity 5.0 in Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-install-unity-5-0-in-ubuntu-11-10/) to install Unity 5.0.

How can I downgrade from Unity 5.0? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the ppa enabled in your sources before running ppa-purge or if quiting a ppa-purge attempt. (1st thing ppa-purge does is disable the ppa to be removed

So open your software sources (software-properties-gtk), re-enable the ppa & then update your sources -

```
sudo apt-get update
```

There is likely no way ppa-purge is going to do a clean, complete job so before using i'd strongly advise to install synaptic.

Then run your ppa-purge command, your best bet may be to accept the 1st solution, Y,  & then answer Y to any other presented until it does it's thing.

Once finished **Do Not** log out or restart

Open synaptic, click 'Reload', then  search gnome-session & mark for install if it's not installed. Then search unity & mark unity for install or re-install.

Additionally search nautilus & mark libnautilus-extension1  for reinstall, check & make sure that nautilus & nautilus-data are installed, if not mark also & apply.

If desired you could search ubuntu-desktop and mark for reinstall in lieu of above, just make sure the packages I've mentioned are installed before you log out or restart

Also note that unity-2d may need to be reinstalled

Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you type `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` first **then** type `sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

1. Remove the PPA.
2. apt-get update
3. apt-get reinstall unity